# What is the c# equivalent for progressive HMACSHA256?

Tags: java, c#, hmac, equivalent

In Java we have progressive hmac like so:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(macKey);
mac.update(part(0));
mac.update(part(1));
...
byte[] fullMac = mac.doFinal(part(n))
```

Please what is the c# equivalent for progressive HMACSHA256?

Comment: [`HMACSHA256` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.aspx) maybe?

Comment: @SonerGönül HMACSHA256

Comment: @SonerGönül how do we do a progressive hash like you can do with java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! Microsoft over-cooked the *otherwise* simple **Update** operation into **TransformBlock** &  **TransformFinalBlock**

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(macKey);
mac.update(part(0));
mac.update(part(1));
...
byte[] fullMac = mac.doFinal(part(9))
```

in .Net this now becomes (vb.net)

```
dim fullMac as byte()
using mac=New HMACSHA256(macKey)
   mac.TransformBlock(part(0),0,part(0).Length,null,0)
   mac.TransformBlock(part(1),0,part(1).Length,null,0)
   ...
   fullMac=mac.TransformFinalBlock(part(9),0,part(9).Length)
end using
```

I don't see how this helps developer-productivity in any way :(